# How long does it take for the carte de séjour (residence permit) to be issued from the date of application?

Tags: visa, france, resident-permit, residency, europe

My spouse and I applied for residency in Nice, France last October 2017. Until now (it's already Mar 30, 2018), we haven't received it yet. What we only have as of the moment is the récépissé, which was issued on January 19, 2018. How long should we still wait to get the actual residence permit? Our visas have already expired and we can't get out of France because of the delay in the residence permit.

Comment: There is no universal answer. Sometimes it can take a few months. Some people just get récépissé after récépissé for years, usually because their documents were mislaid somewhere. It took me something like 6 months in Essonne, but it varies by préfecture.

Comment: It's weird that you got the récépissé all the way back in October and still haven't gotten the card.  It can take time but not like...half a year...since at that point all you're mostly waiting on is for them to make the actual card.  I would go to the prefecture and ask, bringing the récépissé with you--maybe they literally forgot...

Comment: How long does it take for the carte de séjour (residence permit) to be issued from the date of application?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the Préfecture, it can take anywhere from three months to half a year. Normally your récepissé is valid for three months, if memory serves, and you should visit the préfecture when it expires to get it extended. And possibly enquire about your card. Although you'll probably only get a short "Je sais pas" answer...